# How to separate date from a string?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Hi i have the string llike,

"on 01-15-09 witha factor of 0.8"

i wanted to seperate this string in the follwing way,

1] date as 01-15-09
2] Factor of 0.8

NOTE : String length is not fixed.

so how can we seperate the data in the form of #1 & #2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the date you can use `PATINDEX()`.

```
declare @yourString varchar(100)
set @yourString = 'on 01-15-09 with a factor of 0.8'

select substring(@yourString,
            patindex('%[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', @yourString),
            8)
```

To get "factor of xx" you can do:

```
select substring(@yourString,
        patindex('%with a%', @yourString) + 7,
        20)
```

Comment: @VikrantMore not that I know of.  You need a specific pattern to work off of.  The date is easy, but finding the "factor of xx" is impossible unless you know the string that precedes it.  See what I'm saying?

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @txt varchar(max)
set @txt = 'on 01-15-09 witha factor of 0.8'

select cast(substring(@txt, patindex('% [0-9][1-9]-%', @txt), 9) as date) [date], 
cast(right(@txt, patindex('%_ %', reverse(@txt))) as decimal(9,1)) Factor
```

Result:

```
date       Factor
---------- ------
2009-01-15 0.8
```