# sql query to find a column value with specific text available

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is their any other way to find a column values with the specified text available in it.

i know their is one way like,

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%sample_text%'
```

and i tried

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE CONTAINS(COLUMN_NAME,'sample_text')
```

also but it requires table to be full-text indexed

Comment: So, you need to make a full-text index on it. It is much faster and useful than LIKE.

Comment: explain your question properly

Comment: @Rohan S : Do you want to know how to use `Contains()` or some other ways or some other better ways ?

Comment: need other better ways than `LIKE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PATINDEX():

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE PATINDEX('%sample_text%', COLUMN_NAME) != 0
```

Comment: How to Compare with date ?

Comment: Do you need something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081303/how-to-separate-date-from-a-string)?

Answer (score 0):

**Query 1**

```
select 1 where patindex('%find_string%','find_stringfdasfsa')> 0
```

**Query 2**

```
select 1 
where  len(REPLACE('find_stringfdasfsa','find_string',''))<LEN('find_stringfdasfsa')
```

**Query 3**

```
select 1 
where CHARINDEX('find_string','find_stringfdasfsa') > 0
```

Execution plan is same as `Like`. You will have to check the performance.